# Java escpos charset encoding

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding

i have to print a raw text printer where i have to se the codepage charset. I found that the best charset for my application is the IBM858. 
Now the problem is to encode the strings to this codepage.

I tried this:

```
test = new String("#$@°\\è^ùàòèì\n".getBytes(),"Cp858");
file.write(test.getBytes());
```

but chars don't match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This encodes the UTF-16 string as Cp858:

```
file.write("#$@°\\è^ùàòèì\n".getBytes("Cp858"));
```

Comment: It works! Thank you. However it miss some particular chars like uppercases "ÙÀÒÈÌ", euro simbol etc. But it is better than mapping every 128 chars!!

Comment: Those upper case letters are present in Cp858; the Euro symbol is not supported. It sounds like Cp858 is not the correct character encoding.

Comment: Maybe i found the problem, it misses the negative values... for example the euro symbol is (dec)213 (hex)DE and if i run this code: Integer.toHexString("€".getBytes("Cp858")[0]) i se "ffffffd5" and not only "d5" :-/

Comment: I got. Using new PrintStream(stream,true,"Cp858") it well works!

Answer (score 5):

With ESC/POS printer dealing with international charset you have to :

- **set the code page of the printer** : for instance `ESC t 40` will select the code page `ISO8859-15`. i.e. in Java `outputStream.write( new byte[]{ 0x1B, 0x74, 40 } );`
- **encode the string** you want to print with the same code page : `outputStream.write(theStringToPrint.getBytes("ISO8859-15"));`

You must check with your specific printer the code page available and the number to use in the `ESC t n` command. [The EPSON ESC/POS documentation](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=32) for the `ESC t` lists code pages available for EPSON printer.

For EPSON printers, useful documentation is found in the page [Character Code Tables for TM printers](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_charcode_en/index.php?content_id=1).  Check the `Single-byte Characters/Code Pages` section.

**Don't use the International Character Sets** and the `ESC r n` command : it will replace some ASCII character to be able to print some international character with a ASCII code page, it's outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Printing with raw text printer i completely solved with this:

```
new PrintStream(stream,true,"Cp858")
```

however with

```
file.write("#$@°\\è^ùàòèì\n".getBytes("Cp858"));
```

the printer misses some chars, i don't know if it was a printer or java trouble.