# Android Thermal printer Arabic Issue

Tags: java, android, unicode, printing, arabic

```
public class Globals {
    // TODO IMPORTANT CONFIG CHANGES
    // ** IMPORTANT CONFIGURATION
    private static String serverRealUrl = "http://www.myserver.com/api";    //Real Server configuration
    private static String serverLocalUrl = "http://localhost:80/api";             //local configuration
    /**
     * Substitute you own sender ID here. This is the project number you got
     * from the API Console, as described in "Getting Started."
     */

    public static String SENDER_ID = "000000";
    public static String base64EncodedPublicKey = "xxxxx";
    //DEBUG MODO
    public static boolean debugModeBoolean = true;  //USE in DEBUG MODE
    //public static boolean debugModeBoolean = false;  //USE in REAL  MODE


    //PRINT FROM WEB ENABLES
    //public static boolean printFronWebEnabled = true;  //USE to activate print fron web
    public static boolean printFronWebEnabled = false;  //USE  to deactivate print fron web

    //GCM Register
    //public static boolean gcmRegisterEnabled = true;  //USE to register device in GCM
    public static boolean gcmRegisterEnabled = false;  // not use gcm services


    //IN APP BILLING
    //public static boolean inAppBillingModeON = true;  //USE in pay app modo on
    public static boolean inAppBillingModeON = false;  //USE in pay app modo off


    private static String internalClassName = "Globals";    // * Tag used on log messages.
    public static int deviceType = 0;                       // * Device type
    //0 Pending config (Default as start)
    //1 NET Print
    //2 RS232   ->Pending
    //3 USB
    //4 BT

    //Google subscriptions
    public static boolean mSubscribedToYearlyUsed = false;


    // Bluetooth  variable Config
    public static BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    public static BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    public static BluetoothDevice mmDevice;


    public static String logoProcesed = "";

    public static OutputStream mmOutputStream;
    public static InputStream mmInputStream;


    // NET Printer Config
    public static String deviceIP = "";
    public static int devicePort = 0;
    public static int usbDeviceID = 0;
    public static int usbVendorID = 0;
    public static int usbProductID = 0;
    public static String blueToothDeviceAdress = "";
    public static int blueToothSpinnerSelected = -1;

    public static String tmpDeviceIP = "";
    public static int tmpDevicePort = 0;
    public static int tmpUsbDeviceID = 0;
    public static int tmpUsbVendorID = 0;
    public static int tmpUsbProductID = 0;
    public static String link_code = "";
    public static String tmpBlueToothDeviceAdress = "";


    public static String getServerUrl() {
        String actualServer = "";
        if (debugModeBoolean) {
            actualServer = serverLocalUrl;
        } else {
            actualServer = serverRealUrl;
        }

        return actualServer;
    }

    public static String server_registerPrinter = "registerPrinter";
    public static String server_getData = "getData";
    public static String regid = "";
    public static String picturePath = "";


    public static void savePreferences(SharedPreferences sharedPrefs) {
        Log.i(internalClassName, "savePreferences");


        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
        editor.putString("usbDeviceID", String.valueOf(usbDeviceID));
        editor.putString("usbVendorID", String.valueOf(usbVendorID));
        editor.putString("usbProductID", String.valueOf(usbProductID));


        editor.putString("blueToothDeviceAdress", String.valueOf(blueToothDeviceAdress));


        editor.putString("deviceType", String.valueOf(deviceType));
        //Ethernet
        editor.putString("deviceIP", String.valueOf(deviceIP));
        editor.putString("devicePort", String.valueOf(devicePort));

        editor.putString("link_code", String.valueOf(link_code));
        editor.putString("picturePath", String.valueOf(picturePath));
        editor.putString("logoProcesed", logoProcesed);

        Log.i(internalClassName, "               deviceType=" + String.valueOf(deviceType));
        Log.i(internalClassName, "               deviceIP=" + String.valueOf(deviceIP));
        Log.i(internalClassName, "               devicePort=" + String.valueOf(devicePort));
        Log.i(internalClassName, "               usbDeviceID=" + String.valueOf(usbDeviceID));
        Log.i(internalClassName, "               blueToothDeviceAdress=" + String.valueOf(blueToothDeviceAdress));


        editor.commit();

    }

    public static void savePreferenceskitchen(SharedPreferences sharedPrefs) {
        Log.i(internalClassName, "savePreferences");


        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
        editor.putString("usbDeviceID", String.valueOf(usbDeviceID));
        editor.putString("usbVendorID", String.valueOf(usbVendorID));
        editor.putString("usbProductID", String.valueOf(usbProductID));


        editor.putString("blueToothDeviceAdress", String.valueOf(blueToothDeviceAdress));


        editor.putString("deviceType", String.valueOf(deviceType));
        //Ethernet
        editor.putString("deviceIP", String.valueOf(deviceIP));
        editor.putString("devicePort", String.valueOf(devicePort));

        editor.putString("link_code", String.valueOf(link_code));
        editor.putString("picturePath", String.valueOf(picturePath));
        editor.putString("logoProcesed", logoProcesed);

        Log.i(internalClassName, "               deviceType=" + String.valueOf(deviceType));
        Log.i(internalClassName, "               deviceIP=" + String.valueOf(deviceIP));
        Log.i(internalClassName, "               devicePort=" + String.valueOf(devicePort));
        Log.i(internalClassName, "               usbDeviceID=" + String.valueOf(usbDeviceID));
        Log.i(internalClassName, "               blueToothDeviceAdress=" + String.valueOf(blueToothDeviceAdress));


        editor.commit();

    }



    public static void loadPreferences(SharedPreferences sharedPrefs) {
        Log.i(internalClassName, "loadPreferences");


        usbDeviceID = mathIntegerFromString(sharedPrefs.getString("usbDeviceID", "0"), 0);
        usbVendorID = mathIntegerFromString(sharedPrefs.getString("usbVendorID", "0"), 0);
        usbProductID = mathIntegerFromString(sharedPrefs.getString("usbProductID", "0"), 0);


        link_code = sharedPrefs.getString("link_code", "");
        picturePath = sharedPrefs.getString("picturePath", "");
        blueToothDeviceAdress = sharedPrefs.getString("blueToothDeviceAdress", "x:x:x:x");

        deviceType = mathIntegerFromString(sharedPrefs.getString("deviceType", "0"), 0);
        //Ethernet
        deviceIP = sharedPrefs.getString("deviceIP", "192.168.0.98");
        devicePort = mathIntegerFromString(sharedPrefs.getString("devicePort", "9100"), 9100);
        logoProcesed = sharedPrefs.getString("logoProcesed", "");


        Log.i(internalClassName, "               deviceType=" + String.valueOf(deviceType));
        Log.i(internalClassName, "               deviceIP=" + String.valueOf(deviceIP));
        Log.i(internalClassName, "               devicePort=" + String.valueOf(devicePort));
        Log.i(internalClassName, "               usbDeviceID=" + String.valueOf(usbDeviceID));
        Log.i(internalClassName, "               blueToothDeviceAdress=" + String.valueOf(blueToothDeviceAdress));


    }


    public static void loadPreferenceskitchen(SharedPreferences sharedPrefs) {
        Log.i(internalClassName, "loadPreferences");


        usbDeviceID = mathIntegerFromString(sharedPrefs.getString("usbDeviceID", "0"), 0);
        usbVendorID = mathIntegerFromString(sharedPrefs.getString("usbVendorID", "0"), 0);
        usbProductID = mathIntegerFromString(sharedPrefs.getString("usbProductID", "0"), 0);


        link_code = sharedPrefs.getString("link_code", "");
        picturePath = sharedPrefs.getString("picturePath", "");
        blueToothDeviceAdress = sharedPrefs.getString("blueToothDeviceAdress", "x:x:x:x");

        deviceType = mathIntegerFromString(sharedPrefs.getString("deviceType", "0"), 0);
        //Ethernet
        deviceIP = sharedPrefs.getString("deviceIP", "192.168.0.98");
        devicePort = mathIntegerFromString(sharedPrefs.getString("devicePort", "9100"), 9100);
        logoProcesed = sharedPrefs.getString("logoProcesed", "");


        Log.i(internalClassName, "               deviceType=" + String.valueOf(deviceType));
        Log.i(internalClassName, "               deviceIP=" + String.valueOf(deviceIP));
        Log.i(internalClassName, "               devicePort=" + String.valueOf(devicePort));
        Log.i(internalClassName, "               usbDeviceID=" + String.valueOf(usbDeviceID));
        Log.i(internalClassName, "               blueToothDeviceAdress=" + String.valueOf(blueToothDeviceAdress));


    }

    public static Integer mathIntegerFromString(String inti, Integer defi) {
        //used for preferences
        Integer returi = defi;
        if (!inti.equals("")) {
            try {
                returi = Integer.valueOf(inti);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return returi;

    }




    public static String prepareDataToPrint(String data) {
        //ESC POS Comamnds convertions


        data = data.replace("$bold$", "·27·E·1·");
        data = data.replace("$unbold$", "·27·E·0·");


        data = data.replace("$intro$", "·13··10·");
        data = data.replace("$cut$", "·27·m");
        data = data.replace("$cutt$", "·27·i");

        data = data.replace("$al_left$", "·27·a·0·");
        data = data.replace("$al_center$", "·27·a·1·");
        data = data.replace("$al_right$", "·27·a·2·");

        data = data.replace("$small$", "·27·!·1·");
        data = data.replace("$smallh$", "·27·!·17·");
        data = data.replace("$smallw$", "·27·!·33·");
        data = data.replace("$smallhw$", "·27·!·49·");

        data = data.replace("$smallu$", "·27·!·129·");
        data = data.replace("$smalluh$", "·27·!·145·");
        data = data.replace("$smalluw$", "·27·!·161·");
        data = data.replace("$smalluhw$", "·27·!·177·");


        data = data.replace("$big$", "·27·!·0·");
        data = data.replace("$bigh$", "·27·!·16·");
        data = data.replace("$bigw$", "·27·!·32·");
        data = data.replace("$bighw$", "·27·!·48·");

        data = data.replace("$bigu$", "·27·!·128·");
        data = data.replace("$biguh$", "·27·!·144·");
        data = data.replace("$biguw$", "·27·!·160·");
        data = data.replace("$biguhw$", "·27·!·176·");

        data = data.replace("$drawer$", "·27··112··48··200··100·");
        data = data.replace("$drawer2$", "·27··112··49··200··100·");


        data = data.replace("$enter$", "·13··10·");

        data = data.replace("$letrap$", "·27·!·1·");
        data = data.replace("$letraph$", "·27·!·17·");
        data = data.replace("$letrapw$", "·27·!·33·");
        data = data.replace("$letraphw$", "·27·!·49·");

        data = data.replace("$letrapu$", "·27·!·129·");
        data = data.replace("$letrapuh$", "·27·!·145·");
        data = data.replace("$letrapuw$", "·27·!·161·");
        data = data.replace("$letrapuhw$", "·27·!·177·");


        data = data.replace("$letrag$", "·27·!·0·");
        data = data.replace("$letragh$", "·27·!·16·");
        data = data.replace("$letragw$", "·27·!·32·");
        data = data.replace("$letraghw$", "·27·!·48·");

        data = data.replace("$letragu$", "·27·!·128·");
        data = data.replace("$letraguh$", "·27·!·144·");
        data = data.replace("$letraguw$", "·27·!·160·");
        data = data.replace("$letraguhw$", "·27·!·176·");


        data = data.replace("$letracorte$", "·27·m");
        data = data.replace("$LETRACORTE$", "·27·m");


        data = data.replace("$ENTER$", "·13··10·");

        data = data.replace("$LETRAP$", "·27·!·1·");
        data = data.replace("$LETRAPH$", "·27·!·17·");
        data = data.replace("$LETRAPW$", "·27·!·33·");
        data = data.replace("$LETRAPHW$", "·27·!·49·");

        data = data.replace("$LETRAPU$", "·27·!·129·");
        data = data.replace("$LETRAPUH$", "·27·!·145·");
        data = data.replace("$LETRAPUW$", "·27·!·161·");
        data = data.replace("$LETRAPUHW$", "·27·!·177·");


        data = data.replace("$LETRAG$", "·27·!·0·");
        data = data.replace("$LETRAGH$", "·27·!·16·");
        data = data.replace("$LETRAGW$", "·27·!·32·");
        data = data.replace("$LETRAGHW$", "·27·!·48·");

        data = data.replace("$LETRAGU$", "·27·!·128·");
        data = data.replace("$LETRAGUH$", "·27·!·144·");
        data = data.replace("$LETRAGUW$", "·27·!·160·");
        data = data.replace("$LETRAGUHW$", "·27·!·176·");



        data = data.replace("á", "·160·");
        data = data.replace("à", "·133·");
        data = data.replace("â", "·131·");
        data = data.replace("ä", "·132·");
        data = data.replace("å", "·134·");

        data = data.replace("Á", "·193·");
        data = data.replace("À", "·192·");
        data = data.replace("Â", "·194·");
        data = data.replace("Ä", "·142·");
        data = data.replace("Å", "·143·");


        data = data.replace("é", "·130·");
        data = data.replace("è", "·138·");
        data = data.replace("ê", "·136·");
        data = data.replace("ë", "·137·");
        //data = data.replace("","··");


        data = data.replace("É", "·144·");
        data = data.replace("È", "··");
        data = data.replace("Ê", "··");
        data = data.replace("Ë", "··");

        data = data.replace("ñ", "·164·");
        data = data.replace("Ñ", "·165·");

        //data = data.replace("","··");


        data = data.replace("í", "··");
        data = data.replace("ì", "·141·");
        data = data.replace("î", "·140·");
        data = data.replace("ï", "·139·");
        //data = data.replace("","··");


        data = data.replace("ó", "·149·");
        data = data.replace("ò", "··");
        data = data.replace("ô", "·147·");
        data = data.replace("ö", "·148·");
        //data = data.replace("","··");

        data = data.replace("Ó", "··");
        data = data.replace("Ò", "··");
        data = data.replace("Ô", "··");
        data = data.replace("Ö", "·153·");
        //data = data.replace("","··");

        data = data.replace("ú", "··");
        data = data.replace("ù", "·151·");
        data = data.replace("û", "··");
        data = data.replace("ü", "·129·");
        //data = data.replace("","··");


        data = data.replace("ú", "··");
        data = data.replace("ù", "·151·");
        data = data.replace("û", "··");
        data = data.replace("ü", "·129·");

        //data = data.replace("..", "");

        for (int l = 0; l <= 255; l++) {
            data = data.replace("·" + String.valueOf(l) + "·", String.valueOf(((char) l)));
            data = data.replace("$codepage" + String.valueOf(l) + "$",  String.valueOf(((char) 27)) + "t" + String.valueOf(((char) l)));
        }

        Log.d("here----", ""+data);

        return data;
    }

    //Convert string in Byte asccii to print
//    public static byte[] stringToBytesASCII(String str) {
//        byte[] b = new byte[str.length()];
//        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
//            b[i] = (byte) str.charAt(i);
//        }
//        Log.d("bytes=-===", ""+b.toString());
//        return b;
//    }

    public static byte[] stringToBytesASCII(String input) {
//        int length = input.length();
//        byte[] retVal = new byte[length];
//
//        for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
//        {
//            char c = input.charAt(i);
//
//            if (c < 127)
//            {
//                retVal[i] = (byte)c;
//            }
//            else
//            {
//                retVal[i] = (byte)(c - 256);
//            }
//        }
//
//        return retVal;
        return stringToBytesASCIIOK(input);
        // return createImageFromText(100, 500,18 ,input, "Center");
    }




    // generate demo text
    public static String getDemoText(Resources resources, Context context) {
        String dataToPrint = "";

        StringBuilder textData = new StringBuilder();
        textData.append("$codepage32$");
        textData.append("$al_center$$al_center$");

        textData.append("$big$"+M.getBrandName(context)+"$intro$");
        textData.append(M.getRestAddress(context)+"$intro$");
        textData.append("Phone: "+ M.getRestPhoneNumber(context)+"$intro$");
        textData.append("GST# "+ M.getGST(context)+"$intro$");
        textData.append("--------------------------------------$intro$");
        textData.append("Order By : "+ M.getWaitername(context)+"\t $intro$");


        textData.append(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date())+"\n");
        textData.append("ORDER # RES11-121"+"\n");

        textData.append("--------------------------------------\n");
        textData.append("TOKEN # "+21+"\t"+ "dine in" +"\n");



        textData.append("--------------------------------------\n");

        textData.append("Order comment \t");
        textData.append("need spicy" + "\n");

        textData.append("--------------------------------------\n");


        String qty = "1";

        textData.append(padLine(qty + "    Cheese Mayo Fries", 120 + "", 40, " ") + "\n");
        textData.append(padLine(qty + "    Chocolate Milkshake", 130 + "", 40, " ") + "\n");
        textData.append(padLine(qty + "    Veg Sandwich", 100 + "", 40, " ") + "\n");
        textData.append(padLine(qty + "    بيتزا ", 120 + "", 40, " ") + "\n");
        textData.append(padLine(qty + "   بيتزا ", 130 + "", 40, " ") + "\n");
        textData.append(padLine(qty + "   بيتزا ", 100 + "", 40, " ") + "\n");

        textData.append("--------------------------------------\n");

        textData.append("--------------------------------------\n");


        textData.append("SUBTOTAL                    "+350+"\n");
        textData.append("CGST @"+6+"%                    "+21+"\n");
        textData.append("SGST @"+6+"%                    "+21+"\n");



        textData.append("TOTAL       392"+"\n");



        textData.append("CASH                         400"+"\n");
        textData.append("CHANGE                     "+8+"\n");

        textData.append("--------------------------------------\n");


        textData.append("Thank you  "+"Visit Again\n");


//        dataToPrint = dataToPrint + "$codepage0$$intro$";
//        dataToPrint = dataToPrint + Globals.getImageDataPosPrinterLogo(resources);
//
//        dataToPrint = dataToPrint + "$bighw$PosPrinterDriver.com$intro$$intro$";
//        dataToPrint = dataToPrint + "$big$ ESC/POS Types:$intro$ ";
//        dataToPrint = dataToPrint + "$small$ ·36·small·36· ->Small type letter$intro$";
//        dataToPrint = dataToPrint + "$big$ ·36·big·36· ->Big type letter$intro$";
//
//
//        dataToPrint = dataToPrint + "$big$ ESC/POS functions:$intro$ ";
//        dataToPrint = dataToPrint + "$big$ ·36·cut·36·: Cutt paper$intro$ ";
//        dataToPrint = dataToPrint + "$big$ ·36·cutt·36·: Cutt total paper$intro$ ";
//        dataToPrint = dataToPrint + "$big$ ·36·drawer·36·: Open drawer 1 $intro$ ";
//        dataToPrint = dataToPrint + "$big$ ·36·drawer2·36·: Open drawer 2 $intro$ ";
//
//        dataToPrint = dataToPrint + "Specials characters capabilities $intro$";
        //test to find page codes
        //for (int l = 50; l <= 255; l++) {
        //  datos=datos+    "valor "+ String.valueOf(l) + "= ·" + String.valueOf(l) + "·";
        //}
     /*   String defTextToPrint="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ $intro$aáàâäå  AÁÀÂÄÅ $intro$eéèêë  " +
                "EÉÈÊË$intro$iíìîï IÍÌÎÏ $intro$oóòôö OÓÒÔÖ $intro$uúùûü UÚÙÛÜ $intro$ñ Ñ €  $intro$";



        dataToPrint = dataToPrint + "$codepage0$$intro$";
        dataToPrint = dataToPrint + "Select code page 0 PC437 [U.S.A., Standard Europe]$intro$";
        dataToPrint = dataToPrint + defTextToPrint;

        dataToPrint = dataToPrint + "$codepage1$$intro$";
        dataToPrint = dataToPrint + "Select code page 1 [Katakana]$intro$";
        dataToPrint = dataToPrint + defTextToPrint;

        dataToPrint = dataToPrint + "$codepage2$$intro$";
        dataToPrint = dataToPrint + "Select code page 2 PC850 [Multilingual]$intro$";
        dataToPrint = dataToPrint + defTextToPrint;

        dataToPrint = dataToPrint + "$codepage3$$intro$";
        dataToPrint = dataToPrint + "Select code page 3 PC860 [Portuguese]$intro$";
        dataToPrint = dataToPrint + defTextToPrint;

        dataToPrint = dataToPrint + "$codepage4$$intro$";
        dataToPrint = dataToPrint + "Select code page 4 PC863 [Canadian-French]$intro$";
        dataToPrint = dataToPrint + defTextToPrint;

        dataToPrint = dataToPrint + "$codepage5$$intro$";
        dataToPrint = dataToPrint + "Select code page 5 PC865 [Nordic]$intro$";
        dataToPrint = dataToPrint + defTextToPrint;

        dataToPrint = dataToPrint + "$codepage17$$intro$";
        dataToPrint = dataToPrint + "Select code page 17 PC866 [Cyrillic]$intro$";
        dataToPrint = dataToPrint + defTextToPrint;

        //0 PC437 [U.S.A., Standard Europe]
        //1 Katakana
       // 2 PC850 [Multilingual]
       // 3 PC860 [Portuguese]
       // 4 PC863 [Canadian-French]
       // 5 PC865 [Nordic]
       // 17 PC866 [Cyrillic #2]
        dataToPrint = dataToPrint + "$codepage31$$intro$";
        dataToPrint = dataToPrint + "Select code page 31 HEBREW $intro$";
        dataToPrint = dataToPrint + defTextToPrint;


//


        if (Globals.picturePath != "") {
            dataToPrint = dataToPrint + Globals.getImageData();
        }
        Log.e(internalClassName, "dataToPrint" + dataToPrint);*/
//        dataToPrint = dataToPrint +"$intro$$intro$$intro$$intro$$cutt$$intro$";
        textData.append("$intro$$intro$$intro$$intro$$cutt$$intro$");

        dataToPrint = textData.toString();
        return dataToPrint;
    }

    protected static String padLine(@Nullable String partOne, @Nullable String partTwo, int columnsPerLine, String str){
        if(partOne == null) {partOne = "";}
        if(partTwo == null) {partTwo = "";}
        if(str == null) {str = " ";}
        String concat;
        if((partOne.length() + partTwo.length()) > columnsPerLine) {
            concat = partOne + str + partTwo;
        } else {
            int padding = columnsPerLine - (partOne.length() + partTwo.length());
            concat = partOne + repeat(str, padding) + partTwo;
        }
        return concat;
    }

    protected static String repeat(String str, int i){
        return new String(new char[i]).replace("\0", str);
    }
    public static final byte GS =  0x1D;// Group separator
    //get actual logo data
    public static byte[] getImageData(Bitmap bitmap) {

//        if (Globals.picturePath!=null && Globals.picturePath != "") {
//            if (Globals.logoProcesed.length() > 0) {
//                //response with calculated logo data text
//                return Globals.logoProcesed;
//            } else {
//                byte[] bytes1  = new byte[4];
//                bytes1[0] = GS;
//                bytes1[1] = 0x76;
//                bytes1[2] = 0x30;
//                bytes1[3] = 0x00;
//
//                byte[] bytes2 = BytesUtil.getBytesFromBitMap(bitmap);

        return getBytesFromBitMap(bitmap, 32);
//            }
//        } else {
//            return "";
//        }
    }

    public static byte[] stringToBytesASCIIOK(String str) {
        String TAG = "posprinterdriver_AsyncNetPrint";

        byte[] b = new byte[0];
        try {
            b = str.getBytes("US-ASCII");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


//        byte[] b = new byte[str.length()];
//        if (str.length() > 0) {
//            Log.i(TAG, "                 Caracter de 2 partes=" + str + " ->parte1=" + str.charAt(0) + "->" + str.charAt(1));
//
//        }
//      for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
//
//          b[i] = (byte) str.charAt(i);
//
//
//      }
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {

            b[i] = (byte) str.charAt(i);
            Log.i("", "                CAdena encontrada=" + i + " ->parte1=" + str.charAt(i) + " ->parte1=" + (int) str.charAt(i));

        }

        return b;

    }
```

I have Android app, which is working very well with English printing from the thermal printer. The code is perfect. But the problem is when I pass Arabic characters or any other Unicode it does not print properly.

The problem is with a code page. I tried different codepage which supports Arabic as well as Unicode while converting strings to byte. It shows the proper string in the log also of Arabic, but when It prints it does not work.

Note: My printer supports Arabic and codepage is 32. I need a universal printer solution. I am not using Epson SDK. I am using ESC/POS commands.

Comment: It may help to list what printer / software version you are testing against.

Comment: I am using Epson Tm-30 .. If i print character byte I can see arabic printed.. so its not that its not supporting..

Comment: see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640030/java-escpos-charset-encoding

Comment: Could the problem be that you are getting the bytes as us-ascii? I don't think that it supports most characters. (stringToBytesASCIIOK method)

Answer (score 1):

most easy would be to use the Epson SDK; because it does not care if it's an Epson printer - only the vendor ID in the device-filter for USB devices differs in between the vendors; but Star Micronics and other 100% compatibles work just fine. if you want to write your own driver, which literally means re-inventing the wheel; have a look at [ESC/POS](https://files.support.epson.com/pdf/general/escp2ref.pdf) appendix C, page 73:

for Arabic you'd need to select character table `13` with the `ESC t` command, which is IBM code-page [CP864](https://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/PC/CP864.TXT). the sequence would be: `\x1B \x74 \xD`. the output also would have to be encoded as `CP864`, converted from `UTF-16`, so that it matches the code-page, which the printer then expects.

Comment: So do you mean that Epson SDK will support other pritners as well?

Comment: I tried but I am not able to connect other printers if i use epson sdk. I am looking for solution.

Comment: @MayuriRuparel the question was how to switch the output to Arabic, not how to connect other printers; vendor & product ids are not hard-coded. one can use any that `lsusb` lists. no guarantee it would always be character table `13`, this is only `13` by `ESC/POS` reference implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the character table for your printer and write the corresponding commands to let the printer know that you are printing multi byte characters such as Arabic characters. In my case, I was using sunmi printer and the only thing that worked for me was finding its character table and I wrote the commands and it worked very well. Here's a picture of what they said in the documentation.
[a picture of what they said in the documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiYRm.png)

And this is what I did and it worked perfectly

```
    const utf8Encoder = Utf8Encoder();
final encodedStr = utf8Encoder.convert(invoice.description);
bytes += generator.textEncoded(Uint8List.fromList([
  ...[0x1C, 0x26, 0x1C, 0x43, 0xFF],
  ...encodedStr
]));
```