# How to convert UTF-8 String to String US-ASCI codepage 437 when send String to bluetooth printer with codepage CP437 US-ASCII android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

How to convert UTF-8 String to String US-ASCI codepage 437 when send String to bluetooth printer who is with embeded codepage CP437 US-ASCII from Android studio?

I'm new to Android studio. I have little bit older POS printer with bluetooth. In my app I send to printer some strings for example the name of articles ( items) . Strings are in UTF-8 format from date base and also in utf-8 in String variables in Android Studio. POS printer have embedded codepage CP437 , US-ASCI. How I can transform string variable from UTF-8 to CP437 US-ASCI or replace only special character for example Š,š,Č,č,Ć,ć,Đ,đ,Ž,ž with another, etc S,s,C,c,D,d,Z,z... or maybi define my own nice (normal) visiably character before send to printer .

Thank You very much for answers...

I tray on this way, but it not work good. Print results are hieroglyphics for special letters...

```
 nameitem=substring(format("%1$"+ (-18)+"s",somearray[0]),0,18);             

 byte[] b= nameitem.getBytes("UTF-8");
 nameitem = substring(new String(b, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII),0,18);
 doprint(nameitem);
```

On printer I have hieroglyphics results for that chars(letters) etc:
?1/2ß÷×~a....
I wish to have
CcScD..
Or maybe in best solution, defined  on some own way graphically
ČćŠšĐ...

Comment: why don't you want to support Font cultures? your action doesn't make sense !.

Comment: if you want to have StandardCharsets.US_ASCII why you accept UTF-8 text if you have UTF-8 text which support a lot of languages why you change it to StandardCharsets.US_ASCII?

Comment: this is kind of [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... and difficult to answer unless knowing the code-page of the input characters, which happen to be UTF-8 encoded, but still have one. the appendix of these manuals often show them.

Comment: Also a possible duplicate of [Android Thermal printer Arabic Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53909331/android-thermal-printer-arabic-issue/54031768)... it's generally nothing else.